# How to restart track in webrtc video calling

Tags: javascript, html, video, socket.io, webrtc

I implemented video calling using webrtc with use of https://github.com/webtutsplus/videoChat-WebFrontend library. But when I implement switch camera functionality on click of sender at that time sender video stop at receiver end. I followed [Unable to change camera / stream for WebRTC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616178/unable-to-change-camera-stream-for-webrtc-call) link for switch camera.

So anyone please give me a solution regarding this issue.

Thanks.

I tried [Unable to change camera / stream for WebRTC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616178/unable-to-change-camera-stream-for-webrtc-call) for sitch camera but receiver not getting the sender video when switch the camera.

I followed [Unable to change camera / stream for WebRTC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616178/unable-to-change-camera-stream-for-webrtc-call) link to switch camera in video calling between 2 users.

This is the code to switch the camera.

``

```
$(".btn_rear_camera").click(function() {
  if (cameratype == "user") {
      capture('environment');
  } else {
      capture('user');
  }
});

function capture(facingMode) {
  cameratype = facingMode;
  localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      track.stop();
  });
  var constraints = {
      video: {
          deviceId: devicesIds[1]
      },
      audio: true
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
      replaceTracks(stream);
  }).catch(function(error) {

  });
}

function replaceTracks(newStream) {
  var elementId = "localVideo";
  detachMediaStream(elementId);

  newStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      localStream.addTrack(track);
  });

  attachMediaStream(elementId, newStream);

  // optionally, if you have active peer connections:
  _replaceTracksForPeer(peerConnection);

  function _replaceTracksForPeer(peer) {
      peer.getSenders().map(function(sender) {
          sender.replaceTrack(newStream.getTracks().find(function(track) {
              return track.kind === sender.track.kind;
          }));
      });
  }
}

function detachMediaStream(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);

  if (elem) {
      elem.pause();

      if (typeof elem.srcObject === 'object') {
          elem.srcObject = null;
      } else {
          elem.src = '';
      }
  }
};

function attachMediaStream(id, stream) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);

  if (elem) {
      if (typeof elem.srcObject === 'object') {
          elem.srcObject = stream;
      } else {
          elem.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      }

      elem.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          elem.play();
      };
  } else {
      throw new Error('Unable to attach media stream');
  }
};
```

``

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I Edit the question to add code to switch camera when 2 users are connecting into the call.